# Rowunselect without ctrl+click

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Is there a possibility to unselect a row without to hold the control key,only by clickin on it? By that I mean, if you click on an already selected row, it should unselect, without having to hold the control key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested with Primefaces 3.4.2:
xhtml page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function test(xhr, status, args){
                    if(args.unselecttest % 2 == 1){
                        stest.unselectAllRows();
                    }
                }
            </script>
<p:dataTable widgetVar="stest" selectionMode="single" selection="#{tabview.car}"
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="test(xhr, status, args);" />
```

Bean:

```
private int count = 0;

    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Car car) {
        if (car.equals(this.car)) {
            count++;
            RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            reqCtx.addCallbackParam("unselecttest", count);
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
        this.car = car;
    }
```

Comment: How do i do that if I have a multiple selection dataTable?

Comment: no,multiple is imposible, you must use control key, you imagine how get multiple if not use control key :)

Comment: @leostiw you can really avoid Control-Key by using RichFaces datatable component with "multiple keyboard-free" option enabled. [RichFaces DataTable - Multiple Keyboard-Free](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable&sample=exTableSelection&skin=blueSky) Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I got the sollution.

I just overrired the primefaces.js, actually, i just copy the part of Primefaces.Datatable and just remove the condition that says it was required to unselect the row using CtrlKey.

Here the example:

The Original javascript quote:

```
onRowClick: function (e, d, a) {
    if ($(e.target) .is('td,span:not(.ui-c)')) {
      var g = $(d),
      c = g.hasClass('ui-state-highlight'),
      f = e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey,
      b = e.shiftKey;
      if (c && f) {
        this.unselectRow(g, a)
      } else {
        if (this.isSingleSelection() || (this.isMultipleSelection() && e && !f && !b && this.cfg.rowSelectMode === 'new')) {
          this.unselectAllRows()
        }
        if (this.isMultipleSelection() && e && e.shiftKey) {
          this.selectRowsInRange(g)
        } else {
          this.originRowIndex = g.index();
          this.cursorIndex = null;
          this.selectRow(g, a)
        }
      }
      PrimeFaces.clearSelection()
    }
  },
```

You just change this part to this:

```
onRowClick: function (e, d, a) {
    if ($(e.target) .is('td,span:not(.ui-c)')) {
      var g = $(d),
      c = g.hasClass('ui-state-highlight'),

      // I changed it to true
      f = true; 

      b = e.shiftKey;
      if (c && f) {
        this.unselectRow(g, a)
      } else {
        if (this.isSingleSelection() || (this.isMultipleSelection() && e && !f && !b && this.cfg.rowSelectMode === 'new')) {
          this.unselectAllRows()
        }
        if (this.isMultipleSelection() && e && e.shiftKey) {
          this.selectRowsInRange(g)
        } else {
          this.originRowIndex = g.index();
          this.cursorIndex = null;
          this.selectRow(g, a)
        }
      }
      PrimeFaces.clearSelection()
    }
  },
```

if you need some help, you can send me a message.

Answer (score -1):

use jquery toggle function.

```
$(selector).toggle();
```

Comment: Could you be more specific pleasa? I'm using primefaces datatable btw.